# How to create a proper miniscus effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

[image]

I'm trying to create a still render of a glass container with some honey in it. Thanks to 9th grade science class, I know that whenever a liquid is in a container, a miniscus is formed. I'm trying to create the same effect in blender by curving up the liquid towards the edges using a bevel:
[image]
[image]

The problem is, when rendered, the liquid material looks too dense. Normally, the density of the liquid fades towards the top of the edge, however I don't know how to recreate that so it ends up looking equally dense at the thinnest part and the thickest.

Honey:
[image]

Comment: What node setup are you using for honey material?

Comment: Also I've checked several images with honey in glass containers and this darker edge is what you want to have: http://i.ndtvimg.com/i/2016-12/honey-lemon-620_620x350_41480678317.jpg